# Java Array Indexing

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

```
    class anEvent{ 
  String number;
  String dueTime;
 }



public static void main(String args[]) {
      int x = args.length / 2;
      int y = args.length;
      anEvent [] order = new anEvent [x];
      for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
       if(i==0){
        order[i].number = args[0]; //Line(#)
        order[i].dueTime = args[1];
       } else if ( i % 2 == 0){
       order[i].number = args[i];
       order[i].dueTime = args[i];
       } else if ( i % 2 != 0){
        order[i].number = args[i+1];
        order[i].dueTime = args[i+1];
       } else if ( i == x -1){
        order[i].number = args[x-1];
        order[i].dueTime = args[x-1];
       }

      }
```

Java complains that a Null Pointer exceptuion is present at line  # in the above snippet.

What's the matter?

ps: I know that the snippet can be cleaned up but there should be no problem at all on line #

Comment: You didn't specify a line number?

Comment: Did you try walking though this with a debugger? A problem like this should be quick to identify with it.  jdb is usable and then eclipse and netbeans have integreated debuggers....

Comment: I commente line # in the code (sorry if ambiguous).
I'm a newbie to eclipse (and java) I still haven't been taught about the debugger.

Comment: I think the # mark is enough. I wish more people posted the code when describing the problem ( Just use 4 spaces to indent and it will be perfect )

Answer (score 6):

When an array is created, all the array elements are null. In your case, you need to fill the array with `new anEvent()` instances.

Comment: Sorry, but: "Give a Man a Fish, Feed Him For a Day. Teach a Man to Fish, Feed Him For a Lifetime"  :-)   I'm joshing with you but I though it was relevant.

Comment: I wrote anEvent [] order = new anEvent [x];
isn't that enough?

Comment: @frantic: no, that is not enough; as Chris wrote, it creates an array containing only nulls.

Comment: @frantic: No, it is not enough. You just allocated an array with x components in it. All the components in the array are null at this point. You should also allocate instances of anEvent class and assign them into the array components

Comment: @Frank: I agree, and usually for people with homework questions I go to great lengths to avoid giving explicit answers. But you can see from the OP's responses that they don't even know where to begin. Asking them to try to find it using a debugger would just...not get anywhere useful. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Make the first line of your for-loop:

```
order[i] = new anEvent();
```

As is, you are not initializing anything in the array (they're all null), so when you try to access the fields you get that exception.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention that it "can be cleaned up", I took the liberty of so doing:

```
public class Thing {
    private String number;
    private String dueTime;

    public Thing(String number, String dueTime) {
        this.number = number;
        this.dueTime = dueTime;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = args.length / 2;
        Thing[] order = new Thing[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                order[i] = new Thing(args[0], args[1]);
            } else if (i % 2 == 0) {
                order[i] = new Thing(args[i], args[i]);
            } else if (i % 2 != 0) {
                order[i] = new Thing(args[i + 1], args[i + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

"anEvent" doesn't conform to the capitalized camel-case Java standard, so I renamed it.  "Thing" isn't particularly meaningful, but there isn't much to work with here.  The final `else if` clause can never be reached, because `i % 2` either *is* or *is not* equal to zero, so I dropped it.  And, of course, I'm creating new Things, which avoids the problem of the nulls.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

`NullPointerException` means that you attempted to add a value or execute a method to something that turn out to be a null.

In Java object references can have assigned ... well, `objects` and `null`

When they have null assigned this exception is thrown:

```
Object o = null;
o.toString(); // <- NullPointerException ( think of null.toString() )
```

Arrays, are objects also. When you create an array with a size, all the "boxes" inside the array contain `null` as reference.

So:

```
Object[] array = new Object[10];
```

Creates something similar to the following:

```
 [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
```

That's why, when you execute:

```
array[0].toString(); // or  order[i].number in your specific example...
```

You get that exception, because the effect is exactly the same as:

```
null.toString();  // or null.number  <-- NullPointerException.
```

To solve this problem, you have to assign a valid object reference to that position into the array:

```
for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
    order[i] = new anEvent();
    ...
    ...
```

I hope this helps.

Final note. In Java classes names start with upper case, so your class should've really be:

```
class AnEvent {
....
```

And finally, most of the java source code is indented using 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You hasn't created any anEvent instance, defining an array (order[]) you are not creating default values for it.

and also there are more simple array for your case:

```
List events = new ArrayList(x);
for(int i=0; i<y; i+=2){
  anEvent event = new anEvent();
  anEvent.number = args[i];
  anEvent.dueTime = args[i+1];
  events.add(event);
}
anEvent[] order = events.toArray();
```